# How do I install an HTC Android phone for debugging in Ubuntu

Tags: android, debugging

I followed the instructions on [the official site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up), but it doesn't work.

I created an `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules` file as root, containing the text

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

`0bb4` matches the code for my device:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0bb4:0c91 High Tech Computer Corp.
```

I then ran `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules` and restarted `udev`.  I then killed `adv` and ran `adv devices`:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

There's no list of devices, even though I've removed and reconnected my mobile phone several times.

**What am I doing wrong?  Is there someplace I can get help with this?**

Comment: memory stick emulation == Turn on USB Storage , yes

Comment: official site talk about a 51-android.rules not a 70-android.rules .. may be the device is not taken into account due to a "too low udev priority rule" in addition in your rule you didn't mention group as described in the official site (device owner group)

Comment: On OpenSuse 11.4 the rule android / HTC is different , it may works for Ubuntu aswell (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The name of the `android.rules` file, as well as the syntax that you use for the directives within the file, changes subtly with each release of Ubuntu.  Just to keep you on your toes.

[This blog post details what you need to do](http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/), for the version of Ubuntu you have.  Natty Narwhal isn't listed, but my experience is that you can follow the instructions for Maverick Meerkat and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your device is not is memory stick emulation
Check that  your device "Setting"/Applications/Develoment/USB Debugging is checked

on OpenSuse 11.4 my rule for HTC is different than yours

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

may be it may works for you as well

Comment: I have no idea how to check it's not memory stick emulation. Is that "Turn on USB Storage"?  Because I haven't.  Also, "USB debugging connected" is displayed.

Comment: memory stick emulation == Turn on USB Storage , yes

Comment: official site talk about a 51-android.rules not a 70-android.rules .. may be the device is not taken into account due to a "too low udev priority rule" ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your computer? As stupid as it may seem, I had exactly the same problem and it was solved by restarting the computer. I think I have read this somewhere around here, but I can't find where anymore... anyway, some places do recommend you to restart your computer when dealing with this issue on Ubuntu ([like here](http://www.mlindgren.ca/archives/186)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have had issue with this (70-android.rules) as well... 10.04 Lucid Linux (Ubuntu) 64 bit... I finally got it to work by defining each parameter for the phone I was working with... Example below..

To find parameters use the lsusb command [and run it when phone is in each mode]

```
# Wildfire S Marvelc
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ff9", MODE="0666", OWNER="<insink71>" #Normal Marvelc
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cc0", MODE="0666", OWNER="<insink71>" #Debug Marvelc
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cb0", MODE="0666", OWNER="<insink71>" #Recovery Marvelc
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ff0", MODE="0666", OWNER="<insink71>" #Fastboot Marvelc
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Rob